# Gem 'jquery-ui-rails' is not available in SDK 'RVM: ruby-2.3.1'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

So I am trying to use jquery-ui in a rails app. I put `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'` and run `bundle install`. I have `Using jquery-rails 4.2.1`
and `Using jquery-ui-rails 6.0.1`. But I don't have an application.js file. 
In node_modules folder I have : [image]

but not jquery-ui, even though I also tried to get it via npm

in gemfile when I hover over jquery-ui-rails I get `Gem 'jquery-ui-rails' is not available in SDK 'RVM: ruby-2.3.1'`

is there anything else I should do? I searched a lot but couldn't find a solution. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.